# How to type a filename in the ASP.NET FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, controls

I'm Using the ASP.NET FileUpload Control for the first time and so far its working, except one thing: It seems that it is not possible to type a path and filename like

C:\Temp\myfile.txt

into the FileUpload control directly. I always have to use the OpenFileDialog.

**Is there a way to enable the text box of the FileUpload control, so I can type into it?**

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: It should work. [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.90).aspx): "The FileUpload class displays a text box control and a browse button that enable users to select a file on the client and upload it to the Web server. The user specifies the file to upload **by entering the full path of the file on the local computer (for example, C:\MyFiles\TestFile.txt) in the text box of the control**. Alternately, the user can select the file by clicking the Browse button, and then locating it in the Choose File dialog box."

Comment: Although each browser handles it differently, this seems to be a browser issue rather than anything related to FileUpload itself - behind the scenes, ASP.NET turns this into an `<input type="file" />` control.  Chrome doesn't show a textbox at all - just a button and a label - and IE9 shows a read-only textbox and button.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. I believe the reason for this is that you could theoretically write javascript to populate it with "c:\path\to\awesome\file.txt" and upload it silently without the user's knowledge, therefore it's not possible to type stuff into it or pre-populate it in any way.